# naming and storing fileinformation for comparison

Tags: python, class

I am currently working on a script that automatically syncs files from the Documents and Picture directory with an USB stick that I use as sort of an "essentials backup". In practice, this should identify filenames and some information about them (like last time edited etc.) in the directories that I choose to sync.
If a file exists in one directory, but not in the other (i.e. it's on my computer but not on my USB drive), it should automatically copy that file to the USB as well. Likewise, if a file exists in both directories, but has different mod-times, it should replace the older with the newer one.

However, I have some issues with storing that information for the purpose of comparing those files. I initially thought about a file class, that stores all that information and through which I can compare objects with the same name.
Problem 1 with that approach is, that if I create an object, how do I name it? Do I name it like the file? I then would have to remove the file-extension like .txt or .py, because I'd run into trouble with my code. but I might have a notes.odt and a notes.jpg, which would be problem 2.

I am pretty new to Python, so my imagination is probably limited by my lack of knowledge. Any pointers on how I could make that work?

Comment: Can you explain what your file class would look like? Surely you could store the filename including the extension.

Comment: The init function would contain the name and modtime. name includes the filename.fileextension, modtime would be a formatted version of the epoch time. I would like to get the objectname without extension, which still leaves the problem of name duplicates. If i dont delete the fileextension i have problems calling the object because it would look some like `grid.txt.name,` which python does not like